# Using images as points in `ListPlot`

Tags: plotting, image

I am trying to make a `ListPlot` with a bunch of points, each of which I want represented with a distinct image (e.g. `*.png`).  I've tried the following code as an example (with `img` standing for a pasted image).

```
ListPlot[{Style[{1, 1}, img], Style[{-1, -1}, Red]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium, Black], 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, AbsoluteThickness[1.5], 
   AbsoluteThickness[1.5]}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

> [image]

As you can see, `Style[{-1,-1}, Red]` successfully makes the image `Red`, but using the same pattern with an `img` doesn't work.

**NOTE:** I'm aware of `PlotMarkers -> {img1, img2, ...}`, but the problem with this pattern is that it makes it associate which image should go with each data point. It'd be nice if I can find a way to do this where the data point and the image are kept tightly together in one data structure.

---

**EDIT:** Substituting for `img` the following works:

```
Labeled[{1, 1}, Import[
   "https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2018/12/spikey-\
wolfram-logo.png"], Center]
```

The problem is that I'd like the logos to show up as bigger. Adjusting to

```
img = Import[
   "https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2018/12/spikey-\
wolfram-logo.png", ImageSize->Large];
```

does not fix the issue. So my new question is: how (using this method), can I control the size of the image labels to be larger?

Comment: Does `Labeled[{1, 1}, img, Center]` (instead of  `Style[{1, 1}, img]` ) give what you need?

Comment: kglr: That works, but raises a new issue. I modified my question above.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** A more convenient approach is to generate a list of `Inset`s with the desired images using the fourth argument of `Inset` to control the sizes:

```
img = Import[
 "https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2018/12/spikey-wolfram-logo.png"]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[77]
n = 20;
colors = RandomColor[n];
positions = RandomReal[50, {n, 2}];
image = RemoveBackground[img, {"Background", White}];
imglist = ColorReplace[image, Red -> #] & /@ colors;
sizes = RandomInteger[{10, 70}, n];

insets = MapThread[Inset[#, #2, Center, Offset[#3]] &, {imglist, positions, sizes}];
```

***ListPlot***

You can use `insets` as plot markers in `ListPlot`:

```
Show[ListPlot[List /@ positions, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  PlotMarkers -> (Graphics /@ insets),  
  Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]], ListLinePlot[positions]]
```

[image]

or as `Prolog` or `Epilog` option value

```
ListPlot[positions, Joined -> True, Prolog -> insets, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

***BubbleChart***

or with `BubbleChart` as `ChartElements`:

```
BubbleChart[Flatten /@ Thread[{positions, sizes}], 
 ChartElements -> (Graphics /@ insets), 
 BubbleSizes -> {.1, .3}, 
 Epilog -> {ColorData[97][1], Line@positions}]
```

[image]

***Graphics***

or  directly as graphics primitives in `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{insets, Blue, Line @ positions}, ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
img = Import[
  "https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2018/12/spikey-wolfram-logo.png"]
```

You can wrap `img` with [`Magnify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Magnify.html):

```
ListPlot[{Labeled[{1, 1}, Magnify[ColorReplace[img, Red -> Blue], .3], Center], 
  Labeled[{1, 1}/2, Magnify[img, .15], Center], 
  Labeled[{-1, 0}/2, Magnify[ColorReplace[img, Red -> Orange], .45], Center], 
  {-1, -1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 24}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium, Black], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can wrap it with `Style` with the option [`ImageSizeMultipliers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html):

```
ListPlot[{Labeled[{1, 1}, Style[img, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {.2, 1/2}], Center], 
  Labeled[{1, 1}/2, Style[img, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {.1, 1/2}], Center], 
  Style[{-1, -1}, Red]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium, Black], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]